# multiple python kivy Switch widgets with loop - but only one can be activated/deactivated

Tags: python, kivy

I want to make a `python` `kivy` gui with multiple `Switch` widgets.

The problem's that when I run my code, only one of the `Switch` widgets (`my switch 3`) works. Specifically, I can turn `my switch 3` on and off no problem, but if I try to turn on `my switch 2` or `my switch 1` nothing happens.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.switch import Switch

class SwitchClass(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SwitchClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size=(600, 200)
        switch_widgets = [('my switch 1', switch1_callback), 
                      ('my switch 2', switch2_callback), 
                      ('my switch 3', switch3_callback)] 
        for increment, switch_widget in enumerate(switch_widgets):   
            self.add_widget(Label(text = switch_widget[0], pos=(25, increment*50+50)))              
            self.settings_sample = Switch(active = False, pos=(125, increment*50+50))               
            self.add_widget(self.settings_sample)                   
            self.settings_sample.bind(active = switch_widget[1])   
                
def switch1_callback(switchObject, switchValue):
    pass 

def switch2_callback(switchObject, switchValue):
    pass 

def switch3_callback(switchObject, switchValue):
    pass 
        
class SwitchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SwitchClass()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
     SwitchApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)` of each of your `Label`  and `Switch` widgets means that they are all filling the entire `SwitchClass`. So the last `Switch` added (`'my switch 3'`), gets the mouse click first and claims it without allowing the other `Switch` widgets a chance. To fix it, just specify a size for those widgets, like this:

```
class SwitchClass(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SwitchClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (600, 200)
        switch_widgets = [('my switch 1', switch1_callback),
                          ('my switch 2', switch2_callback),
                          ('my switch 3', switch3_callback)]
        for increment, switch_widget in enumerate(switch_widgets):
            print(increment, switch_widget)

            # provide sizes for the widgets:
            self.add_widget(Label(text=switch_widget[0], pos=(25, increment * 50 + 50), size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50)))
            self.settings_sample = Switch(active=False, pos=(125, increment * 50 + 50), size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50))

            self.add_widget(self.settings_sample)
            self.settings_sample.bind(active=switch_widget[1])
```